# jQuery click anything but link with class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having some trouble toggling classes.

Updated with [js-fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cfj3g9e4/)

When a delete link is clicked a new confirmation link slides into view. If the confirmation-link is also clicked then the table row shall be deleted.

If the user clicks *anywhere* else but this link the link should slide back out of view by toggling the classes delete-btn-show and delete-btn-hide.

Hope this clarifies things :)

Below is a table listing. Each row has a trash-can icon which opens a div (.delete-btn) by toggling classes. If a delete-btn is visible (has class .delete-btn-show) it should hide itself by toggling classes (delete-btn-show/-hide) if anything else but the link within it is clicked. If the link is clicked it should delete that row. I've managed to show the div but am unable to achieve the desired behaviour. Help is welcome :)

(The jQuery is within a document ready function)

```
$('.delete-supplier-link').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().parent().find('.delete-btn').toggleClass('delete-btn-show delete-btn-hide');
});


<a class="delete-supplier-link" href="#">
  <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
```

Here is the table structure

```
<table class="table table-hover" id="curr-suppliers-listing">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="suppl-org">
          Some organization
        </span>
        <span class="supplier-of">
          Some product or service
        </span>
        <span class="supplier-contact">
          Some dude
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="alignR">
        <div class="delete-btn delete-btn-hide">
          <a class="delete-string" href="#">
            Delete
          </a>
        </div>
        <span>
          D.O.P.
        </span>
        <span>
          2011-11-12
        </span>
        <span>
          <a class="delete-supplier-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="suppl-org">
          Some organization
        </span>
        <span class="supplier-of">
          Some product or service
        </span>
        <span class="supplier-contact">
          Some dude
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="alignR">
        <div class="delete-btn delete-btn-hide">
          <a class="delete-string" href="#">
            Delete
          </a>
        </div>
        <span>
          D.O.P.
        </span>
        <span>
          2011-11-12
        </span>
        <span>
          <a class="delete-supplier-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <span class="suppl-org">
          Some organization
        </span>
        <span class="supplier-of">
          Some product or service
        </span>
        <span class="supplier-contact">
          Some dude
        </span>
      </td>
      <td class="alignR">
        <div class="delete-btn delete-btn-hide">
          <a class="delete-string" href="#">
            Delete
          </a>
        </div>
        <span>
          D.O.P.
        </span>
        <span>
          2011-11-12
        </span>
        <span>
          <a class="delete-supplier-link" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
          </a>
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly what you asking, but, check this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yp9znej8/

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.delete-btn-show', function() {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        // to remove the table line when clicking the button
        // using .delete-btn-show to only remove when the button is visible
    });
});
```

If it's not what you looking for, you should change your question for better readability.

@UPDATED

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L1nsanqf/3/

The thing is to stop propagation of events, so it doesn't conflict with other event..
Don't know if it's the best way of doing this.. but, works, and I think this is what you want

Comment: this is pretty good. One thing though, if the class delete-btn-show has been assigned to a div (i.e. a delete-button has come into view) the other links which also slides the delete link into view should not slide another delete link into view if one is already visible. Instead it should close any visible delete link and then the next time a trash-icon is clicked it should slide the delete link into view. In other words, you shall not be able to view more than one delete link at a time.

Comment: that's a one line code: http://jsfiddle.net/L1nsanqf/5/
keep in mind that you should refactor this code as there's several improvements that can be done..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use this code :

```
$('.delete-btn').each(function () {
   $(this).click(function () {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });
  });
```

For each div with 'delete-btn' as css class, it defines the function linked to the click event which deletes the row.

Answer (score 0):

You could have click bubble all the way up to `<body>`, check if $(this) is a delete-btn, and respond accordingly:

```
$("body").on( "click", function(){
    if ( $(this).hasClass("delete-btn") ){
        // Do some deleting, this is a delet button!
    } else {
        // Hide the button, this is some other element
        $(".delete-btn").removeClass("delete-btn-show").addClass("delete-btn-hide");
    }
});
```